# Issue with Navbar icon in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I need to add the icon for my navbar, so I have downloaded the icon from the following link,http://www.glyphish.com/, I have downloaded the free icons. then I am trying to add the icons in the code, I cons are not displaying? What's wrong with code?

```
<div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a id="other-color" data-icon="img/193-location-arrow.png" data-iconpos="left" href="#">Set Filter</a></li>
                    <li><a id="other-color" data-icon="img/193-location-arrow.png" data-iconpos="right" href="#">Add page</a></li>
                </ul>
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create custom classes and modify their `background-image` using `:after` pseudo selector.

```
.ui-arrow:after {
  background-image: url(../193-location-arrow.png);
  background-size: 15px 15px;
}

.ui-location:after {
  background-image: url(../07-map-marker.png);
  background-size: 20px 20px;
}
```

> [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/G7DLF/)

Comment: If I want to use the image from folder, url(img/193-location-arrow.png); Will this works? img is my folder name