# How to style data-icons dynamically in jquery mobile 1.4.2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have just updated my jquery mobile code from 1.3.1 to 1.4.2 in my Framework.
The challenge I am facing is to style my data-icons conditionally based on developer's parameters.

code for 1.3.1,

```
myButton.find('.ui-icon').css('background-color',iconColor);
```

in 1.4.2 jQuery uses pseudo class `:after` for the icons and since its not a part of the DOM  it is inaccessible by JavaScript.

I can achieve it(but don't want to do it for the performance) by changing the DOM of the icon element?
Is there any other way?

Comment: the only way is to create custom classes http://stackoverflow.com/a/24578631/1771795 in case you want to use custom icons. to change jQM icons, simply, add related icon class to button.

Answer (score 0):

If you use case allows you to select from a pre-determined list of icon background colors, you can set classes for each color and then switch them out in code.

Given a button with an icon:

```
<button id="btnIcon" class="ui-btn ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-left ">Button</button>
```

Here are 3 classes that set the background color to red, green , and blue respectively:

```
.redIcon:after {
    background-color: #97080E;
}
.greenIcon:after {
    background-color: #488C13;
}
.blueIcon:after {
    background-color: #1B55C0;
}
```

Then in script, you remove all color classes and then add the one you want to take effect:

```
$("#btnIcon").removeClass("redIcon greenIcon blueIcon").addClass(className);
```

> **Here is a working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/C9j6x/)**

Click the buttons marked red, green, and blue to see the icon update.

Comment: its a good approach but the use case is different...the developer should be able to pass any color(which may change too tomorrow).
I just copied the computed styles for the after pseudo element and made my own div with images. Thanks